# Testing git submodule in context

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

We have a project that contains several submodules, and I'd like to set up CI for these.

Build scripts are part of the main project, so a proper test would be to check out the main, replace the submodule by the merge candidate, and build using the mail repo.

Is there a good way to automate this process in GitLab, or do I need to write a long shell script?